# Verify if contains Request.QueryString in enum list

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

How Can I verify if contains Request.QueryString in enum list?
E.g.:
I have a `enum`:

```
enum queryString
{
    monday,
    tuesday,
    wednesday,
    thursday,
    friday,
    saturday,
    sunday
}
```

Get enum values:

```
var enumQueryString = Enum.GetValues(typeof(queryString)).Cast<queryString>().ToList();
```

I tried

```
Request.QueryString["days"].Contains(enumQueryString.ToString())
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < enumQueryString.Count; i++)
        if (Request.QueryString["days"].Contains(enumQueryString[i].ToString()))
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

But in the last case don't work correctly, because of iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the other way around: you should check `enumQueryString` list:

```
var enumQueryStringList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(queryString)).Cast<queryString>().ToList();
if (enumQueryStringList.Contains(Request.QueryString["days"])) {
    ...
}
```

You can do it without LINQ, too:

```
queryString qs;
if (Enum.TryParse<queryString>(Request.QueryString["days"], out qs)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot!!